# Como recuperar o atributo de um elemento criado dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Os elementos são gerados dinamicamente, graças a isso ele não existe no DOM.
Meu caso é o Seguinte:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">';
<div class="ui-block-a">'+row.nome_item+' id '+row.id_item_conta+'<div class="valor_quantidade" quantidade_item="'+quantidade+'">'+quantidade+' X '+row.valor_item+'</div></div>
<div class="ui-blok-b"><a href="javascript:0" id_item_conta="'+row.id_item_conta+'" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right soma_item_conta" style="background: none; border: none;float:right;margin-top:5px;"></a><a href="javascript:0" id_item_conta="'+row.id_item_conta+'" class="ui-btn ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-right diminui_item_conta" style="background: none; border: none;float:right;margin-top:5px;"></a></div>
</div>
```

Esses elementos são gerados dinamicamente e colocados dentro de uma `div` com  determinado `id`:

```
<div id="conta_selecionada"></div>
```

Até ai tudo bem, repare que existe um *link* com a classe `soma_item_conta` para reconhecer esse *link* é fácil pois existe um evento atrelado a ele.

```
$('#conta_selecionada').on('click','.soma_item_conta',function(){
     //alert('TETSE');        
});
```

Porem aí começa o meu problema. Eu preciso recuperar o valor do atributo `quantidade_item` que foi gerado dinamicamente junto com o *link* `a`... Porem como ele não tem nenhum evento atrelado ao mesmo eu não consigo recuperar junto com o `on`.

Alguém tem alguma solução?

Comment: Se você usar a classe em vez do ID para selecionar o componente, os eventos associados a ele serão anexados também aos novos controles criados com a mesma classe. Ex: `$('.classe_deste_e_dos_novos_componentes').on('click'...`.

Comment: Não entendi @Caffé poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Fui eu que não entendi sua pergunta. Se os novos elementos são criados dentro da div `#conta_selecionada` e se estes novos elementos recebem a classe `soma_item_conta`, então a maneira como você associa código ao evento click destes novos elementos (`$('#conta_selecionada').on('click','.soma_item_conta',function(){...`) está correta. Cada novo elemento, quando clicado, deve disparar o seu código pois o evento foi associado a um elemento previamente existente (`#conta_selecionada`) e delegado a seus elementos filho de classe `soma_item_conta'`. De modo que não consegui entender seu problema.

Comment: Amigo Obrigado seguinte os elementos são criados dinamicamente o atributo quantidade_item não é filho  de soma_item_conta e sim irmão.
 e ele não tem nenhum evento associado  ao mesmo apenas preciso pegar o valor do attr.

Comment: Edite a pergunta de modo a deixar isso mais claro. Considere mostrar mais html e JavaScript relevantes. Considere também mostrar o html já resolvido em vez das concatenações de string. Tenho a impressão que sua dúvida pode ser muito facilmente resolvida aqui no SO desde que seja adequadamente formulada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma Solução rápida seria colocar a chamada da função diretamente no seu elemento criado dinamicamente. Exemplo:

```
function selecionaConta() {
       $('#conta_selecionada').on('click','.soma_item_conta',function(){
          //alert('TETSE');

       });
}

<div class="ui-blok-b"><a href="javascript:0" onclick="selecionaConta()" id_item_conta="'+row.id_item_conta+'" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right soma_item_conta" style="background: none; border: none;float:right;margin-top:5px;"></a><a href="javascript:0" id_item_conta="'+row.id_item_conta+'" class="ui-btn ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-right diminui_item_conta" style="background: none; border: none;float:right;margin-top:5px;"></a></div>
```

Esse eu diria que não é o melhor cenário, mas acho que já te ajudaria.

Comment: Pensei nisso tbm porem não queria fugir do padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra solução seria:

```
function selecionaConta() {
       $('#conta_selecionada').on('click','.soma_item_conta',function(){
          //alert('TETSE');

       });
}
```

Pega o script ou evento que cria seus elementos dinâmicos e faz a chamada do seu script.

```
function criaEelmentos() {
  //cria seus elementos dinâmicos aqui

  selecionaConta();
}
```

Espero que agora ajude :)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa navegar para o elemento que contém o atributo, com base em onde ele está em relação ao elemento clicado. No caso, ele está numa div `.ui-block-a` que é irmã da que contém o link (`.ui-blok-b`):

```
$('#conta_selecionada').on('click','.soma_item_conta',function(){
    var container = $(this).closest('.ui-blok-b');
    var anterior = container.prev('.ui-block-a');
    var alvo = anterior.find('.valor_quantidade');
    var valor = alvo.attr('quantidade_item');
    alert(valor);
});
```

<sub>Um detalhe: para que seu HTML seja válido, você não pode ter atributos customizados como "quantidade_item". Adicionar o prefixo `data-` ao nome do atributo resolveria esse problema.</sub>